# Why pygame.sprite causes "maximum recursion depth" in my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I made this simple class and for some reason it crashes python and I dont know why

This is the code

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):
    def __init__(self, pos, size):
        super().__init__()
```

and this is the error I get

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entity.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):
  File "C:\Users\playe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\playe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "C:\Users\playe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "C:\Users\playe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
  File "C:\Users\playe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 137, in add
    if hasattr(group, '_spritegroup'):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 2):

`pygame.sprite.Sprite()` creates an object. For the base class, you only need to specify the name of the class. See [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Change `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` to `pygame.sprite.Sprite`

<s>`class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):`</s>

```py
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
```

Comment: wow, you're fast, I saw it right after posting this question.

Thank you for helping :3